# Jbuilder Build Multidimensional Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, jbuilder

Jbuilder code:

```
json.array!(@venues) do |venue|
  json.extract! venue, :id, :name, :longitude, :latitude, :price_range, :venue_category_id, :venue_images, :address, :short_description, :max_capacity
end
```

In my models each 'Venue' has_many 'Venue_Images'. The JSON above is giving me an array of objects for venue_images within the main venues array, as expected.

The venue_image objects are like this:

```
#<Item:0x007fc97559b960> {
                    :id => 1,
    :image_content_type => "image/jpeg",
       :image_file_name => "chanel.jpg",
       :image_file_size => 28880,
      :image_updated_at => 2012-04-09 21:00:08 UTC
}
```

I need to iterate over the venue images in the jbuilder code somehow so I can call Paperclip/S3 helpers (i.e .image.url(:medium)) on them, as these aren't available in the JS view. I need to get these urls into the @venues array rather than all the other properties of the paperclip object, so I can iterate through them in the JS and display them in my view.

What's the best way to do this? I've tried a few different blocks and looked at the jbuilder wiki and a couple of articles, but can't get anything to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, is this what you had in mind:

```
json.array!(@venues) do |venue|
  json.extract! venue, :id, :name, :longitude, :latitude, :price_range, :venue_category_id, :address, :short_description, :max_capacity

  json.venue_images venue.venue_images do |vi|
    json.url vi.image.url(:medium))
    json.id vi.id
    json.image_content_type "image/jpeg"
    json.image_file_name "chanel.jpg"
    json.image_file_size 28880
    json.image_updated_at "2012-04-09 21:00:08 UTC"
  end
end
```

This should give you a JSON hash like this:

```
"venue": {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Foo",
  "longitude": "180 degrees",
  "latitude": "90 degrees",
  "price_range": "100-200",
  "venue_category_id": 2,
  "address": "500 Poop Lane",
  "short_description": "Blah blah, foo foo",
  "max_capacity": 500,

  "venue_images": [
    {
      "url": "http://poop.com",
      "id": 5,
      "image_content_type": "image/jpeg",
      "image_file_name": "chanel.jpg",
      "image_file_size": 28880,
      "image_updated_at": "2012-04-09 21:00:08 UTC" 
    },
    etc.
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me give it a try this morning and come back to you!